# How do I add a long reply to my question?

Tags: discussion, support

I posted a question about about installing libmcrypt on Snow Leopart, & it was replied to, but the the suggestion in the reply didn't work & I feel like I need to add information related to what happened, the output of a command. However, the # of characters in the reply box is too small for me to add this information. What's the proper way to add a long reply? Do I need to edit the original question to do it?

Comment: Yep, just edit your original question. That's the preferred way to add additional information to your question.

Answer (score 2):

If your reply at all adds more information to the question, please edit your question and add it.
Comments should not add substantial/important details to a question, that is what editing is for.

If you need to alert a specific user that you did add that information, you can add a comment to the effect of `"@user see the edit to my question"`.